# Is Geopandas fully written in python language?

Tags: python-3.x, visualization, geopandas

I have used VegaLite.jl to plot a choropleth map in Julia. And Geopandas to plot the same in Python.

As I want to make a benchmark between both I would like to know if Geopandas has been fully written in Python or if it is just a wrapper?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoPandas itself is written in pure python, but it depends on fiona, rtree, pyproj and shapely. All of them are using C libraries to do the work. Fiona GDAL, rtree libspatialindex, pyproj PROJ6 and shapely GEOS.

Regarding plotting, GeoPandas uses matplotlib. I see that matplotlib has some C code, but not sure if it is used in this case.